# Does a handled SIGINT affect pipe communication with a child process?

Tags: pipe, signals, sigint

I have an interactive C program that reads a phrase from the terminal, and computes a series of anagrams. I also have a Perl program that reads and buffers lines from STDIN until receiving a reserved "end of input" token, sorts the lines, organizes them into columns and sends them to STDOUT. The C program uses the BSD/MacOS `popen()` to start the Perl program with a single bi-directional pipe, and `fprintf()`'s the anagrams on the pipe until it's generated all the anagrams; sends the "end of input" token, and then issues `getline()`'s on the pipe to read back and print the formatted results.

It works fine normally. But I added a SIGINT handler to the C program so I could interrupt a long-running anagram, print whatever results it had thus far, and loop around for more terminal input. The handler sets a flag that the main program checks after writing to the pipe. If it's set, it breaks out of the anagramming loop and proceeds as if the loop had ended naturally: it sends the end-of-input string, and reads back the formatted results.

It breaks out okay; the `fprintf` end-of-input gets a normal return code; but the first `getline` returns a null pointer indicating EOF, so I don't get any partial results. The C program continues normally, as intended.

I don't find anything in the docs to indicate that a handled SIGINT affects any open pipes, but I can't think what else would be preventing me from receiving anything from the Perl program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SIGINT` signal goes to every process in the foreground process
group; the foreground process group will typically include whatever the
`popen` runs,

```
/* popen.c */
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void poke(int unused) { fprintf(stderr, "sigint - C\n"); }
int main(void) {
    FILE *fh;
    signal(SIGINT, poke);
    fh = popen(
      "exec perl -e '$SIG{INT}=sub {warn q{ouch}};sleep 1 while 1'",
      "r+");
    if (!fh) abort();
    while (1) sleep(1);
    return 42;
}
```

as can be verified with something like:

```
$ make popen
$ ./popen
^Csigint - C
ouch at -e line 1.
^Csigint - C
ouch at -e line 1.
^\Quit
```

Therefore, all the programs must handle the signal, or the signal can be
turned off in the terminal. Details will vary by language, but to ignore
a signal in Perl one can simply ignore it:

```
$SIG{INT} = "IGNORE";
```

Another option is to [block the signal in a parent process](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/raw/master/signal/blocksig.c), though
subsequent programs might install their own signal handlers.

Yet another option is to disable the `ISIG` flag in the terminal. In this
case <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will not cause a signal to be sent
to the foreground process group; instead, a character will be available
for some program to read. See the `termios` manual page for details (the
man page section will vary by operating system). An interface such as
curses might be typical here, though one could instead make a suitable
`tcsetattr(3)` call to disable `ISIG`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# example script showing how control+c can be read as a key
use strict;
use warnings;
use Curses;
initscr;
noecho;
raw;    # disables ISIG, among other things
while (1) {
    my $ch = getchar() // die "getchar failed??";
    last if $ch eq 'q';
    move 0, 0;
    clrtoeol;
    addstring sprintf "key: %vx", $ch;
}
endwin;
```

This should display `key: 3` when <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is pressed; a signal will not be sent to the foreground process group. Type `q` to exit.